# Copiar pasta Pai com FTP e WinSCP em arquivo bat

Tags: batch, ftp

Fala galera, belezinha?

To me aventurando criando pra mim uma ferramenta de backup pra um FTP, e estou utilizando o WinSCP pra fazer a conexão e usar o comando synchronize pra mim.

```
set FTPSERVER=MEUHOST
set FTPUSER=USUARIO
set FTPPASS=SENHA
set LOCALE=C:\arquivos
set FTPREMOTO=\backup
"F:\Programas\WinSCP\winscp.com" /command "open ftp://%FTPUSER%:%FTPPASS%@%FTPSERVER%/" ^
  "synchronize remote ""%LOCALE%"" ""%FTPREMOTO%"" " ^      
exit
```

Bom até aí conecta e faz a cópia bem certinho.

Porém ele apenas copia os arquivos dentro de `C:\arquivos` direto pra pasta `backup`, e não cria a pasta `arquivos`. Eu poderia criar manualmente essa pasta e jogar lá. Mas essa função que estou fazendo vai ser alimentada depois com diversas outras pastas, ai ter que ficar criando uma a uma não compensa.
Existe alguma maneira, de na hora de enviar pro FTP, considerar a pasta pai? Como se fosse um comando `cd..` e capturar essa pasta? 
Assim no meu host iria ficar `backup\arquivos`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"F:\Programas\WinSCP\winscp.com" /command ^
  "open ftp://%FTPUSER%:%FTPPASS%@%FTPSERVER%/" ^
  "option batch continue" ^
  "mkdir backup/arquivos" ^
  "option batch abort" ^
  "synchronize remote ""C:\arquivos"" ""backup/arquivos"" " ^ 
  "exit"
```

Unfortunately, I do not speak Portuguese, so I can provide only English explanation: The point of my answer is to create the subfolder (`mkdir`), but prevent failing in case the subfolder exists already ([`option batch continue`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option#batch)).

*Anyone: feel free to edit my answer with translation.*

Comment: Você poderia trazer juntamente ao seu código uma explicação sobre ele?

Comment: @AndréFilipe I would like to, but unfortuntely, I do not speak Portuguese. -- Anyway, the point of my answer is to create the subfolder (`mkdir`), but prevent failing in case the subfolder exists already (`option batch continue`).

Comment: It worked as needed. Now with some folders can't make it work, but its most likely been a problem with the quotes escapes. But the code with `batch continue` worked perfectly. (Funcionou como precisava. Agora algumas pastas não consigo funcionar, mas é provável que seja por causa das das aspas que precisa escapar corretamente. Mas o código com `batch continue` funcionou perfeitamente